# Help: My German Shepherd has lost his spark

Tags: dogs, training, play

I have a female German Shepherd, 8 months old. When she was young she was playful but also annoying. Things like chewing me so hard dthat I could not walk because you can't walk with a dog hanging on to your legs.

I worked hard to discourage all sort of unruly behavior.

Now she is becoming a grown up dog who won't play with me. I can't get her to play tug of war with me, she won't wrestle and fetch works only halfway, she takes the ball and either runs with it or goes somewhere to chew it
She is still playful with other dogs.

How do I re-encourage playful behavior?

Comment: What exactly did you do to discourage unruly behaviour? And what behaviours EXACTLY did you correct, and what did you allow?

Comment: I discouraged all sort of mouthing. Chewing me (pretty hard, it hurt), chewing my legs while walking etc.

Comment: All? Or just when it comes to you and/or furniture, cords, etc.? Chewing is not bad for a puppy, it's chewing on the wrong things.

Comment: I also discouraged damaging things, but chewing people was a biggie. Especially that he had started to nibble really hard.

Comment: Did you give her alternatives to chew? How did you discouraged her?

Comment: Alternatives to chew: Plenty. She was not chewing me because she needed to chew. She wanted to play with me or communicate with me. How I discouraged her: Say no, lock her in a different room, shake her leash (standard non-violent punishments)

Comment: Does she stay indoors or outdoors?

Comment: Indoors. With my 3 months old Presa Canario

Comment: Check her food. Some dog food does not give enough protein and other health factors to keep her energy up.